# Are questions about the Apple website allowed?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, asking-questions

I've got a quite unusual question here.

Would asking a question about the [Apple website](https://apple.com) directly be on-topic?

If so, what are the specifications or the "checklist" I should follow when asking a question about that?

Comment: It depends on the question :-)

Comment: @nohillside I've got 4 purchases in my Apple Store bag and I would like to share the whole bag to someone (with the all the options for each item carefully set already). This was to be done without taking screenshot/capturing pdf or giving my login credentials to the person. :)

Comment: @nohillside Is the question okay to ask or is it worthless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have plenty of well-received questions in the [apple-store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-store) tag, including questions about the online store. There's even more questions linking to the [Apple Developer Portal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+url%3A%22developer.apple.com%22), so this definitely counts as an Apple products as mentioned in the [tour](/tour). The usual caveat ([What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask)) applies, as it always does.

Comment: Thanks! Have you seen the comment I have posted on the question? Is it alright to ask something like that? :)